# ClassB inherits ClassA. How do I check if ClassA objA is of ClassB type and then convert objA to ClassB?

Tags: c#, types, polymorphism

Say that ClassB inherits ClassA, and that I have an object named objA that is of type ClassA. 
How do I check if objA is of ClassB type and then convert objA to ClassB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var objB = objA as ClassB;
if (objB != null)
{
    // objA is of type ClassB, you can use it via objB
}
```

Or, if you're using C# 7:

```
if (objA is ClassB objB)
{
    // objA is of type ClassB, you can use it via objB
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy and helpful response. Excellent to have you.